# How to execute a query on an unrelated table for every row in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Let's say I have a table like this that tracks the balance of an asset I have in an account:

| Delta | NetBalance | Timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 2 | 2020-01-01 00:00:00.000 |
| 4 | 6 | 2020-01-02 00:00:00.000 |
| -1 | 5 | 2020-01-03 00:00:00.000 |

Let's say I have another unrelated table that keeps of track of pricing for my asset:

| Price | Timestamp |
| --- | --- |
| 1.00 | 2020-01-01 00:00:00.000 |
| 1.02 | 2020-01-01 23:59:00.000 |
| 2.01 | 2020-01-02 10:00:00.000 |
| 2.02 | 2020-01-02 18:00:00.000 |
| 3.01 | 2020-01-03 12:00:00.000 |
| 3.02 | 2020-01-03 13:59:00.000 |

I'm looking for a query that will yield a result set with the columns from the first table, plus the closest price (from the exact moment, or the past) from the second table and its associated timestamp, so, something like this:

| Delta | NetBalance | Timestamp | MostRecentPrice | MostRecentPriceTimestamp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 2 | 2020-01-01 00:00:00.000 | 1.00 | 2020-01-01 00:00:00.000 |
| 4 | 6 | 2020-01-02 00:00:00.000 | 1.02 | 2020-01-01 23:59:00.000 |
| -1 | 5 | 2020-01-03 00:00:00.000 | 2.02 | 2020-01-02 18:00:00.000 |

Working with MySQL here. Would prefer to avoid things like cross joins because the tables themselves are pretty huge, but open to suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use `LAG` window function get previous `Timestamp` from `account` then do `join` with `unrelated` table.

Then use `ROW_NUMBER` window function to get MostRecent data rows.

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT *,
           row_number() OVER(PARTITION BY MONTH(Timestamp),DAY(Timestamp) ORDER BY MostRecentPriceTimestamp DESC) rn
    FROM (
      SELECT a.Delta,
            a.NetBalance,   
            a.Timestamp,
            u.Timestamp MostRecentPriceTimestamp,
            u.Price MostRecentPrice
      FROM (
        SELECT *,LAG(Timestamp,1,Timestamp) OVER(ORDER BY Timestamp) prev_Timestamp
        FROM account a
      ) a
      INNER JOIN unrelated u
      ON u.Timestamp BETWEEN a.prev_Timestamp AND a.Timestamp 
    ) t1
) t1
WHERE rn = 1
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=49b4fadeeaa1b611b12d1772b333b571)

Comment: So, this is an awesome answer. But I want to clarify...what happens if the first timestamp in the pricing table is actually from 2019-12-31 23:59:59.999 instead of 2020-01-01 00:00:00.000? https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=644de830f0c64fe872d687e92eff4f76